# A basic question on measurable rectangles

Tags: measure-theory

In Billingsley, the following statement has been written :

As $\mathscr{R^1} \times \mathscr{R^1} = \mathscr{R^2}$, $\mathscr{X} \times \mathscr{Y}$ is in general much larger than the class of measurable rectangles.

What does this mean ? The class of measurable rectangles need not be a sigma-algebra in general. So, that shows that the sigma algebra generated by the measurable rectangles is much larger than the class of measurable rectangles. Why do we need to prove $\mathscr{R^1} \times \mathscr{R^1} = \mathscr{R^2}$ ?

Comment: You haven't told us what $\mathscr{X}$ and $\mathscr{Y}$ are.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Is not this a standard notation ? otherwise I have to type a lot. In short, the script letter are sigma algebras generated by the corresponding sample space. cross product of two script letter means the sigma algebra generated by the class of measurable rectangles.